# Creating BufferedImage from PApplet contents

Tags: java, servlets, bufferedimage, processing

In my Java servlet that uses Processing, I want it to render the contents of the PApplet to a BufferedImage and produce from it a PNG image.  What's the way to create a BufferedImage from the contents of a PApplet?  The code I have to create the BufferedImage and renders it to browser should work from examples I've seen, but the final image it produces is black/empty.

First I have:

```
private PApplet createPApplet() {
    PApplet p = new PApplet();
    p.init();
    p.noLoop();      
    p.size(486, 243);
    p.background(255);
    p.stroke(255, 255, 255);
    p.colorMode(PApplet.RGB, 256, 1, 1);
    p.translate(p.width/2, p.height/2);
 return p;
```

}

Then in the doGet I have

```
    PApplet p = createPApplet();
    p.loadPixels();
    // here I do some drawing with p.point()
    p.loadPixels();
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(486, 243, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    img.setRGB(0, 0, 486, 243, p.pixels, 0, 256);
    p.draw();
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
    ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", response.getOutputStream());
```

Thanks everyone for your input!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard for me to test your code in a similar environment; but I think the problem is that you call `loadPixels()` after the drawing process and not  [`updatePixels()`](http://processing.org/reference/PImage_updatePixels_.html).

```
PApplet p = createPApplet();
p.loadPixels();
// here I do some drawing with p.point()
p.updatePixels();
```

Give this version a try.